# Using std::copy to copy wide strings on Windows

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a wide string like this

```
std::wstring s(L"Stack Over Flow");
```

that I want to copy into a vector of wide characters `std::vector<wchar_t>` (of a null terminated string ) using `std::copy` 
Both the following approaches seem to work 
First

```
std::vector<wchar_t> c( s.size() + 1 );
std::copy(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.length() + 1, c.begin());
wprintf( L"%s\n",&c[0] );
```

Second

```
std::vector<wchar_t> d( s.size() + sizeof(wchar_t));
std::copy(s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.length() + sizeof(wchar_t), d.begin());
wprintf( L"%s\n",&d[0] );
```

But I am thinking the first should fail because I am not allocating the correct size for the ending null character. What did I miss?
**Edit**
No, I don't want to to this

```
std::vector<wchar_t> c(s.begin(), s.end()); <br>
```

because I am resizing an existing buffer 
**Edit**
By changing the use case (print using the C like API ) I can see that the second version is probably the correct one.
First prints `Stack Over Flow????????`
Second prints `Stack Over Flow`  as expected

Answer (score 6):

Why so much hotchpotch?

I wonder why you're not doing this:

```
std::vector<wchar_t> c(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Simple, and concise!

As for your code, both versions are wrong. Both are wrong because the second argument is going beyond the end, as it should be only `s.c_str() + s.length()`. That is,

```
2nd arg ---> s.c_str() + s.length() //correct

2nd arg ---> s.c_str() + s.length() + 1 //wrong - first version
2nd arg ---> s.c_str() + s.length() + sizeof(wchar_t) //wrong - second version
```

If you follow simple code, idiomatic code, you can avoid much of error.

---

If you use `std::copy`, for example when you cannot use vector constructor for some reason, then the idiomatic `std::copy` is this:

```
void f(std::vector<wchar_t> & c)
{
  //you cannot use constructor version now, so use std::copy as
  std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(c));
}
```

EDIT:

If you're working with C library, and APIs which works with c-string, then I would suggest you to use `std::wstring` (or `std::string`). I don't see much point in using `std::vector`, for it adds confusion to the code. If you use vector, you have to append a null character at the end, so as to make it work:

```
  c.push_back('\0'); //do this after copying!
```

But I still don't see any point in doing that, as you're trying to treat vector like a string. If you need string, why not use  `std::wstring` and it's `std::wstring::c_str()` to get the c-string.

Comment: One for the common reasons to copy a `std::wstring` to a `vector<wchar_t>` is when calling an API that expects a null-terminated `wchar_t*`.

Comment: You'll get +1 from me if you say *why* both versions are wrong ;-)

Comment: @Nawaz I am reinitializing an exsiting buffer so your suggestion wouldn't work unless I copy the string twice. Also as MSalters said the target is useful for passing to C APIs that exist a null-terminated wchar_t

Comment: @user841550: Did you read the answer completely, where I also suggested how to use `std::copy`?

Comment: Only the second one of his goes past the end of an array.  The first reads in the trailing NULL.  @MSalters I find it ammusing you post that comment when your answer does not mantion or considerI it.

Comment: Nawaz, do you have something against vector::assign?  I'd prefer it to std::copy, so you tont have to set the size first.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No. Suppose `std::wstring s= L"abc";` then `s.c_str() + s.length()` will be equivalent to `s.end()`.

Comment: @user841550: No. But it is incorrect. If you get expected result, that would mean that it is by chance you get that. Ideally, your code invokes undefined behavior, which means it could run as expected, or it could not. The Standard gives no guarantee.

Comment: @Nawaz I am yet to be convinced that your answer is correct for this use case. You need to compile both mine and your code and see the results.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, I compiled your code. If you don't allocate storage for the ending null and pass the buffer to wprintf you get this ~Stack Over Flow???????? It compiles but you don't get the correct result

Comment: @user841550: `std::vector` automatically handles that. Why do you care? Also, why don't you post more information? Like what output do you expect, and what you actually get?

Comment: @Nawaz: The problem is that he's passing it to `wprintf` which requires a trailing `NULL`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: If he does that, he is doing that wrong. Why he is using `wprintf` with `vector<wchar_t>`  in the first place? that is another hotchpotch which he should get rid of.

Comment: @user841550: DONT USE `wprintf` with `std::vector`. Use `wcout` with `std::wstring`.  Or tell us what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @Nawaz Please, don't shout. wprintf is just an example of a C like function that I picked at random. When working with C library APIs you have to prepare memory the way the library expects.

Comment: @user841550: I'm not shouting. Emphasizing is not shouting. As for C library APIs, then see my solution. I've edited it.

Comment: @Nawaz OK. now that you agree that we need to push the null at the end don't you agree that my second version of std::copy is actually correct?

Comment: @user841550: Please you study it yourself. I cannot comment on it anymore. I'm kind of busy with my own work. If I get time, I will reply to your query.

Answer (score 3):

When you ask for a `std::vector<wchar_t> c(size)` it allocates enough space to contain size `wchar_t` items - the size you ask for is not in bytes, but is in `wchar_t` items.

Answer (score 1):

First: You don't actually need an ending null character, when you have a size-aware container.

Secondly, this constructor for `std::vector<T>` takes the number of T elements, not bytes. So `+1` means one extra `wchar_t(0)`.

[edit]
With the edited question, the easiest solution seems `c.assign(s.begin(), s.end())`.